# idris cabal install fails. "The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls"

Tags: cabal, cabal-install, idris

I first do the cabal update/upgrade process so I have cabal-install-1.20.0.3. Then I do:

```
cabal install idris
```

I get:

```
...
idris-0.9.14.1 (new version)
The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
network-2.5.0.0
HTTP-4000.2.17
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

(I'm running OS X 10.9.4 if that matters)

Comment: have you tried installing idris into a sandbox? Aside from this you are in the usual cabal-hell-mess - if all else fails you can reset (meaning delete ~/.cabal and maybe the packages under /local/usr/haskell or whereever they are on MacOS) and start from scratch

Comment: btw: here is a nice article explaining how to compile idris from source using a sandbox: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Installing-an-Idris-Development-version-in-a-sandbox

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine (using the 2014 haskell plattform on Linux Mint with only some essential packages like ghc-mod, installed - basically those you need to get sublime-haskell / emacs support - everything else I do in sandboxes) - NOTE: if you get an error about a missing **ltinfo** search for lib32-ncurses-dev or something similar in your systems pacakges and install it (I hope you can find it in homebrew or something similar too)

Comment: thanks guys! Haskell/Cabal are a little more flaky than I expected. Nothing is perfect, of course.

Comment: The Haskell 2014 platform is not available on the major Mac package managers yet: Nix and homebrew.

Comment: most package managers will take a while - why not go with the installer https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:

network-2.5.0.0 
HTTP-4000.2.17

Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.

*or use sandbox as @Carsten suggested*

Comment: I tried --force-reinstalls. It still didn't work. I also haven't tried Haskell 2014 as that still isn't available on any of the major package managers yet. I haven't tried a "sandbox" yet.

Comment: this needs to get figured out. I tried installing agda on 3 platforms, and on two separate operating systems, im getting stuck somewhere on all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Using cabal flag `--avoid-reinstalls` may help.